# What is this worm like animal found on a well water filter?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, invertebrates

This was found in the water filter on a private water well that feeds a house in southeast Colorado, USA. The well has hard water, and is shallow (25’). There are several of these creatures all over the filter. They range from 3mm-5mm long.

The picture is of the water filter. In a video we have of them on the filter they move their arm like appendages.

[image: worm found on water well filter]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE — this looks very interesting! I can think of a couple of marine invertebrates this vaguely resembles, but I have no useful idea about what it might be from well water. Can you [edit] in clearer pictures and/or possibly give a more detailed description of your creatures? Posting a link to your video might also be helpful. ——— Finally, it might be worthwhile to preserve specimens (e.g. stored in a clear high proof alcohol) — that way if no one comes up with a good answer you might be able to find a specialist at a college or university nearby who could identify them. 